# Opencart 2 load template part in template

Tags: php, e-commerce, opencart2.x

For example I have template `home.tpl` in this template I want load `/common/slider.tpl` template. This is possible to load template from 'template' ? and how I can do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible... You have to call the controller of the slider.tpl at the home.tpl controller,

at catalog/controller/common/home.php add the line like

```
    $data['slider'] = $this->load->controller('common/slider');
```

catalog/view/your_theme/template/common/home.tpl add the following line, at which you want the slider

```
   echo $slider;
```

You have to remove following line at controller/slider.php ,

```
if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/slider.tpl')) {
            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/slider.tpl', $data));
        } else {
            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('default/template/common/slider.tpl', $data));
        }
```

and add following lines,

```
    if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/checkout/login.tpl')) {
        return $this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/slider.tpl', $data);
    } else {
        return $this->load->view('default/template/common/slider.tpl', $data);
    }
```

Comment: Now I getting NULL, what I must  return in slider controller ? Now I have:  `$this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('default/template/common/slider.tpl', $data));` So my question is how to return all view with html in slider controller ?